# Python Fuse calling 'readlink' 6 times in a row

Tags: python, linux, fuse

I am implementing a filesystem using Python Fuse.  A directory contains only `symlinks` and as such I return `S_IFLNK | 0777` on the `getattr` method.

Now, when I do an `ls` on the directory, I notice that Linux calls `readlink` method 6 times in a row for *each* entry in the directory.

Is it a bug on my side or a normal behavior?

Comment: That seems buggy, but this is the first time I've encountered Fuse or `readlink`, so I could be wrong!

Comment: Did you ever find the reason for the multiple calls?

Comment: @EthanFurman Unfortunately I didn't keep a record of this. Normally, I would have updated this question but it seems I didn't get to the bottom and most probably went on using a different strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's definitely not ls calling readlink more than once. Unless you're calling it with unusual flags?

```
$ls
entropy  share
$ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 entropy users 14 Aug  8 14:26 entropy -> /home/entropy/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 entropy users 11 Aug  8 14:18 share -> /usr/share/
$ltrace ls 2>&1 | grep readlink
$ltrace ls -l 2>&1 | grep readlink
readlink(0xbfdbb6c0, 0x9549b90, 15, 0, 0xb75ceec8) = 14
readlink(0xbfdbb6c0, 0x954a148, 12, 0xbfdbb992, 0) = 11
$
```

From the looks of things here ls with no flag never calls readlink, and will call it only once per link if the long flag is given. I don't know much about fuse, much less python fuse. So unfortunately, I can't answer your original question beyond saying that this looks very much like buggy behavior on your side but I could be wrong.

Comment: Ah yes, ltrace, strace and a bit of grep make a pretty useful combination for debugging :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you set st_size properly in getattr?  ls will first try with a buffer size of the returned st_size and double it until the the readlink buffer fits.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: I'll try whenever I go back to this project and report.